# How to write in a <array><dict> structure with defaults write?

Tags: macos, bash, plist

I've got a `.plist`-file with a structure like this:

```
<plist version="1.0">
   <array>
      <dict>
         <key>BundleIsVersionChecked</key>
         <false/>
         <key>BundleIsRelocatable</key>
         <false/>
         <key>BundleHasStrictIdentifier</key>
         <false/>
         <key>RootRelativeBundlePath</key>
         <string>value</string>
      </dict>
   </array>
</plist>
```

I want to add or edit the `RootRelativeBundlePath`-key with the `defaults write` command.
Another possibility would be writing the whole plist-file but it has to be the same exact structure.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`defaults` can run out of steam quickly on more complicated structures. When it does, you'll be glad to know of `PlistBuddy(8)`, which hides outside of your `PATH` at `/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy`.

Comment: It seems to be impossible to generate a plist starting with an <array>-element instead of a <dict>-element by using the defaults-command. Therefore your answer is correct.